# Unable to connect to Snowflake using DBeaver via JDBC connection. Getting: "sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found."

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbeaver

I have entered host, user and passwrord and can access the database in Snowflake via the browser but I can't access it via DBeaver jdbc connection. Am using DBeaver vs 4.3.4 and Snowflake driver snowflake-jdbc-3.12.9

Comment: 1. Can you try using latest JDBC version, 3.13.X? 2. Are you using any SSL proxy in your network?

Comment: sure, will try with latest version. About the second point, i have added its certificates to the truststore (in java_home, also in dbeaver jre), should the proxy still block it?

Comment: If the proxy doesn't changes the certificate it should be ok. Try with latest version and lets see if you get same error.